# captured images with HTML5 for mobile devices

Tags: html, api, jquery-mobile, mobile

i am using html 5  `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>`  file element for web mobile
to take photo it works fine but how can i handle file.value to send it to web service or database?
here is demo for mobile devices [Demo link](http://test.yazilim.ca)

here is my code  but does not work
i can not get file upload value

```
   <html>
<script>
function getPhoto()
{
alert('2');
var fu1 = document.getElementById("myfile").value;
alert("You selected " + fu1);
}
</script>
<body>
<form>
<input type="file" name="myfile" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="button" value="get Photo path" onclick="getPhoto()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi robertc i added my code

Comment: Should be `accept="image/*" capture="camera"` I guess? http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the File API: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Here is a nice tutorial from html5rocks.com: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Try doing something like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
```

**JS**

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object, files[0] is your file
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

If you need to read the file in JS, then you need to use the FileReader API.

Comment: document.getElementByID('files') or myfile? with both them   it gives with chrome "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null"  error

Comment: Whoops sorry that's a typo you should add id="myfile" and document.getElementByID('myfile')

Comment: Where is this file stored? I'm using this in conjunction with an iPhone and it works beautifully. I can read the picture taken and show it in the DOM but I'm wondering where is the path to that file?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to give ID to your input tag.
your input tag will be like this

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
```